# how to count the number of items in a list which is nested in a dictionary?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested-lists

hey there I'm learning python and need to count the items in nested lists like below,
so that I can give an answer based on if the person has one or more favourite languages:

```
favourite_languages = {
    'Joe': ['French'],
    'Jim': ['Spanish', 'Portugese'],
    'Alan':['German', 'Swedish']
}
for name, lang in favourite_languages.items():
    if len(name) == 1:
        print(f"{name}'s favourite language is {lang}")
    elif len(name > 1):
        print(f"{name}'s favourite languages are {lang}")
```

Thank you guys very much!

Comment: Can you provide the output you're expecting, and what you're actually getting - and perhaps explain what you don't understand about the mismatch?

Comment: Your approach seems spot on to me. Only a typo there with `len(name > 1)` - suppose that should be `len(name) > 1:`

Comment: It looks like you already have the problem solved. What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you were just checking the length of the wrong variable...

```
favourite_languages = {
    'Joe': ['French'],
    'Jim': ['Spanish', 'Portugese'],
    'Alan':['German', 'Swedish']
}

for name, langs in favourite_languages.items():
    if not len(langs):
        print(f"{name} has no favorite language.")
    elif len(langs) == 1:
        print(f"{name}'s favourite language is {langs}")
    else:
        print(f"{name}'s favourite languages are {langs}")
```

Comment: Wow, yeah it was so close and I somehow overlooked this approach. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

To check the length of each language list inside the dictionary, you could use the **len(NameOfDictionary[key])** expression or **len(value)** directly. For each iteration in the for-loop, the variable `name` has the key stored and the variable `lang` has the value stored, and hence you could use the `len(favourite_languages[name])` expression or `len(lang)` directly.

```
favourite_languages = {
    'Joe': ['French'],
    'Jim': ['Spanish', 'Portugese'],
    'Alan':['German', 'Swedish']
}

for name, lang in favourite_languages.items():
    if len(favourite_languages[name]) == 1:
        print(f"{name}'s favourite language is {lang}")
    elif len(favourite_languages[name]) > 1:
        print(f"{name}'s favourite languages are {lang}")
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thank you! This was something I didn't think of!